# IE page crashed on long process

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, async-await

So the problem i am facing is in internet explorer.
I am trying to fetch data from tableau and download it as an excel file. Data set is huge and is almost 4MB.
using xlxs-populate library for it and all works fine in other browsers like chrome and firefox but in IE the page just crashed within seconds and the download doesn't happen.

So, i tried to add an async function with await to fetch data from the tableau. so it waits for it and page should not crash.

The problem i am facing now is Internet Explorer is showing an error like: it says `Expected ';'`

My async function is:
its showing `Expected ';'` in my async function.

```
  async function startLoop(sellOutDataWorkSheet, summaryDataOptions, sheetDeferred){
    await sellOutDataWorkSheet.getSummaryDataAsync(summaryDataOptions).then(function(summaryData){
      alert('goes in');
    });
  };
```

and i am calling it like:

```
function buildCsvReport(){
   startLoop(sellOutDataWorkSheet, summaryDataOptions, sheetDeferred);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From [this article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function), we can see that the async function doesn't support IE browser.

If you want to use the async function to get the data, you could use [JQuery Ajax async method](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) to call related method or Api to get the data, then, download it.

Besides, [this article](https://www.easeus.com/computer-instruction/internet-explorer-keeps-crashing-freezing-not-responding.html) will provide you 5 effective methods to help you effectively fix Internet Explorer not working, crashing issue, you can check it.